# The Chinese words become a mess in the explorer

Tags: html, delphi, utf-8, character-encoding, lazarus

I want to show something on the website by entering the password, but when the Chinese words came, it became a mess.

```
function hex2int(a){
    if("0"<=a&&a<="9")return a[0].charCodeAt()-48;
    else return a[0].charCodeAt()-55;
}
function crypt(key){
    const ciphertext="D58A9ED7A4B43C3852535157545454"; // encrypt from utf-8, by Lazarus
    const len=ciphertext.length,len2=key.length;
    var cipher2="";
    for(var i=0;i<len/2;i++)
        cipher2+=String.fromCharCode((hex2int(ciphertext[i*2])*16+hex2int(ciphertext[i*2+1]))^(key[i%len2]).charCodeAt());
    return cipher2;
}
function check(){
    var psw=document.getElementById("psw").value;
    if(md5("2020S1S1S"+psw)=="f514e934ca90eac781519284406d80f7"){  // password(psw) is 123
        document.getElementById("main").innerHTML=crypt(psw); // this became a mess
        document.getElementById("verify").innerHTML=""; // 'main' and 'verify' are "div"
    }else alert("Password Wrong.\n\rAccess Denied");
}
```

the `ciphertext` is made by Lazarus, code:

```
function crypt(const plaintext,key:ansistring):ansistring;
var
  i:longint;
begin
  crypt:='';
  for i:=1 to length(plaintext) do
    crypt:=crypt+chr(ord(plaintext[i])xor ord(key[(i-1)mod length(key)+1]));
end; 

function string2hex(a:ansistring):ansistring;
var
  ans:ansistring;
  i:longint;
  function int2hex(a:longint):char;
  begin
    if(a>=0)and(a<=9) then
      exit(chr(a+48))
    else
      exit(chr(a+55));
  end;
begin
  ans:='';
  for i:=1 to length(a) do
    ans:=ans+int2hex(ord(a[i])div 16)+int2hex(ord(a[i])mod 16);
  exit(ans);
end;               

something:=string2hex(crypt(TMemo1.Lines.Text,password));   // it is going to be the "ciphertext"
```

the code is saved as the format of utf-8. the website also used `<meta charset="utf-8">`

Comment: Looks like you are paying the price for treating binary as though it was text. Why don't you consider some actual encryption?

Comment: Maybe I think that my two functions "crypt" are also an "actual" encryption?I just wondered why the text that can be directly shown can't be shown correctly after encryption and decryption. Maybe it's the fault of dynamically add elements to "div"? Can you please recommend some actual encryption that can be both used in Lazarus (Delphi as well) and Javascript?

Comment: There are many standard encryption algorithms available. You should do some research. You must also concentrate on learning that binary and text are not the same thing. When you encrypt some other you must operate on binary data. But your code is treating it all as text.

Comment: Also, your functions are using ansistring. When you use the newer delphi versions with unicode strings, you will loose extended characters like Chinese ones. So basicly as @DavidHeffernan you need to start using better/different encryption algorithms.

Comment: In current Lazarus versions, it is typical that ansistring is utf8. At least for GUI (LCL) programs.